# How can I display array of items in textbox separated with comma?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, textbox

Is there any way to show string array items in textbox seperated with comma. I am unable to get it right, running through lots of trials and errors.

Any help or suggestion with be highly appreciated.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lineNum = 1;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);



            foreach (string line in text)
            {
                if (lineNum <= 30)
                {

                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString( text);

                }
                else
                {
                   textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(text);
                 }
            }
        }
   }
```

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", text);
```

If you want to append `NewLine`  after each comma use:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, text);
```

Also you don't need to use that `foreach` loop.

Edit: According to your comment you can use something like this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, text.Take(30));

if(text.Length > 30)
     textBox2.Text = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, text.Skip(30));
```

**Note:** In order to use `LINQ` methods (for ex. `Take` and `Skip`) you need to include `System.Linq` namespace to your project.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Selman22 it works and displays all items in array in textbox seperated with comma, but as u can see in my codes, i want to display 1st 30 items of the array textbox1 others in textbox2. but the code is skipping condition check.

Comment: @user2889827 I edited my answer.it should do what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

@user2889827 With you code you are making this error: every new loop cycle you replace the hold `Textbox1.Text` with a new string.
For correcting this problem you must concatenate the hold text with the new one:

```
...
textbox1.text+=text;
...
textbox2.text+=text;
```

Also converting a `string` to a `string` it's useless.
Or if you prefer you can use the @Selman22 solution that, in you case, is the best solution for solving the problem